# How to set background image to full screen

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to set a background Image into my html page.

So I have this code:

```
body{
   background: url("background_image.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / 100% auto;
}
```

This is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

So with this code, the background image doesn't fill the screen.

I want to display the image at full width and height

Comment: Please take more care for your language. It is quite hard to understand. I tried to fix it for you, please check if I interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: Is that what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/r3g3ucem/

Comment: yes, is this. Sorry for my english

Comment: You might want to use media queries as well.

Comment: In addition to answers, check https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 5):

Try using this css code :

```
body{
  background: url(backgroud-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

or

```
html{
      background: url(backgroud-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: the code, works in Mozilla Firefox, but, if I try to open my html page, in Goole Chrome, I can't see the all image

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
body{
   background: url("background_image.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top / cover auto;
}
```

hope that helps !